# Is there a way to connect and execute Postman via Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, postman, bdd, postman-collection-runner, newman

I am doing some API Testing using Postman and I have also tried executing the collection via Newman. Our leads are suggesting that what if the execution of the Postman Collection can be done via Cucumber? Is it possible that the Cucumber can read Postman Collection? Given that the Postman scripting that is based on node.js, most of its functions are already written in BDD approach, but they wanted it to be same with Cucumber (with Feature, Scenario, Given, And, When, Then) Let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks!

Comment: you are using cucumber java or javascript ?

Comment: I am not yet using cucumber java or javascript to connect/integrate with Postman. In that case would it be possible?

Comment: https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/#custom-reporters  . you can run newman programitatically. see if custom report function helps

Comment: the main advantage of using postman is using in built in code  snippet ,chai bdd , etc . Overlapping it with cuucmber is like over enginering . You are just wasting efforts .

Comment: @PDHide I'll take note of these details that you have said. I would agree on the part "Overlapping it with cuucmber is like over enginering . You are just wasting efforts ". Anyway, thanks for the details that you have indicated.

Comment: When using cucumber, you're already writing your step definitions in a certain programming language. Why don't you interact with the API using that programming language?